# How to create test wallet for providing NFT and tokens in TZKT api?

Tags: testnet, faucet, tzkt

I need to test API on **ithacanet** network for showing tokens and NFTs.

I'm looking for a way to create a test account (which provides me **passphrase**,**secret key**, and **account address**) and assign some NFTs and Tokens to this account.

Comment: Please make sure you "mark as top answer" on your previous questions, if any of the answers solved your issues. This is an important step on stack exchange so others can see which answer solved your issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a faucet telegram bot by Baking Bad, that works for all active testnets: https://t.me/tezos_faucet_bot

Answer (score 2):

This site: https://teztnets.xyz/

Provides links to the testnets and a "faucet" for each network. You can use this faucet to get an account pre-loaded with XTZ. Many existing wallets, and the CLI will allow you to import these details.